# Какой тип данных использовать?

Tags: html, postgresql, база-данных

Хочу хранить у себя в PostgreSQL ссылки на ролики в ютубе, для последующий вставки плеере на страницы сайта.

Пробовал через тип text, но text он и выводит ссылку как text, поэтому нужно или прям в html указать что этот тип будет частью кода или в бд есть какой-нить спец. тип данных.

Comment: А вы не можете текст преобразовать в ссылку?

Comment: не совсем ссылку (объект <iframe>), но может вы что-то знаете, каким образом преобразовывать :)

Comment: > но может вы что-то знаете, каким образом преобразовывать :)

[HTML <a> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)
[HTML <iframe> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: Тогда сразу напрашивается вопрос, а как вы выводите разметку? Скорее всего при выводе происходит экранирование спец.символов, чего делать в данном случае не надо.